# Friedmann equation in a matter dominated universe?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

Prove that the Friedmann equation in a matter dominated universe is:
$$\dot{R}^2=\frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}R^2-k$$
Where $R$ is a scale factor, $\rho$ is the matter density and $k$ is a positive constant.

Given are:

$$R(\theta)=\frac{4\pi G\rho_0}{3k}(1-\cos \theta)$$
And:
$$t(\theta)=\frac{4\pi G\rho_0}{3k^{3/2}}(\theta-\sin \theta)$$
Where $\theta$ is a variable ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$. In the present day the scale factor is $R_0=1$.

Also:

$$\rho=\rho_0\Big(\frac{R_0}{R}\Big)^{-3}$$

My attempts:

I first derived the parametric equations:
$$\frac{dR(\theta)}{d\theta}=\frac{4\pi G\rho_0}{3k}(0+\sin \theta)=\frac{4\pi G\rho_0}{3k}\sin \theta$$
$$\frac{dt(\theta)}{d \theta}=\frac{4\pi G\rho_0}{3k^{3/2}}(1-\cos \theta)$$
Then I applied the chain rule: $\frac{dR}{d\theta} \times \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ but that didn't yield anything useful.

I then tried to isolate $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ from these equation and tried to apply $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta=1$ but that got complicated and didn't get rid of $t(\theta)$.

Comment: Hi Gert, this is a pretty blatant homework question.

Comment: Hi, Gert! I'm feeling quite weird to say this to a person who is an experienced reputed user and reviewer here; but don't you think this question is HW type and purely lacking conceptual query?

Comment: I agree with both of you. Frustration is a great driver though. Eventually it will be closed but maybe someone will provide the golden tip in the mean time? Sorry for sinning.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear, but I suspect that you're being asked to prove that the given parametric equation for $R(\theta)$ and $t(\theta)$ satisfies the Friedman equation.  If so,  you shouldn't try to get rid of $\theta$ entirely.  Instead, show that the left-hand side (as a function of $\theta$) is equal to the right-hand side (as a function of $\theta$.)  This is pretty easy to do from where you are;  the following trick may be useful:
$$
\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta = (1 - \cos \theta)(1 + \cos \theta).
$$

Comment: I agree, but I think this should be a comment rather than an answer.